# Insert Day of Week into Python Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the average # of sales a restuarant has on each day of the week. There are seven restaurants, not always open on the same day.

Data is structured like this:

[Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faKtt.png)

I've succeeded in converting the date to day of the week with this code:

```
#converting days in table to days of the week
s = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', freq = 'D').to_series()
```

How do I then append the data frame to put this value in, based on the "day" series?

Comment: What is the expected output ??

Comment: If your date column is called day and you want to extract day of week and assign it to the dataframe, you can try something like df['dayofweek'] = df['day'].dt.dayofweek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a dataframe that looks somewhat like this (dataframe modified from example image to contain two locations and a date range over multiple weeks):

```
              location         day  number_of_orders
0          Bryant Park  2018-01-01               394
1          Bryant Park  2018-01-02               807
2          Bryant Park  2018-01-03               744
3          Bryant Park  2018-01-04               791
4          Bryant Park  2018-01-05               677
5          Bryant Park  2018-01-06               294
6          Bryant Park  2018-01-07               503
7          Bryant Park  2018-01-08               434
8          Bryant Park  2018-01-09               591
9          Bryant Park  2018-01-10               877
10  Rockefeller Center  2018-01-01               135
11  Rockefeller Center  2018-01-02               237
```

You could firstly add a `day_of_week` column:

```
df['day_of_week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day']).dt.day_name()
```

So that the dataframe now looks like this:

```
              location         day  number_of_orders day_of_week
0          Bryant Park  2018-01-01               394      Monday
1          Bryant Park  2018-01-02               807     Tuesday
2          Bryant Park  2018-01-03               744   Wednesday
3          Bryant Park  2018-01-04               791    Thursday
4          Bryant Park  2018-01-05               677      Friday
5          Bryant Park  2018-01-06               294    Saturday
6          Bryant Park  2018-01-07               503      Sunday
7          Bryant Park  2018-01-08               434      Monday
8          Bryant Park  2018-01-09               591     Tuesday
9          Bryant Park  2018-01-10               877   Wednesday
10  Rockefeller Center  2018-01-01               135      Monday
11  Rockefeller Center  2018-01-02               237     Tuesday
```

Then you could use this new column to groupby to achieve your desired result:

```
res_df = df.groupby(['location', 'day_of_week']).mean().rename(columns={"number_of_orders": "avg_number_of_orders"})
```

**Output dataframe:**

```
location           day_of_week  avg_number_of_orders               
Bryant Park        Friday                      677.0
                   Monday                      414.0
                   Saturday                    294.0
                   Sunday                      503.0
                   Thursday                    791.0
                   Tuesday                     699.0
                   Wednesday                   810.5
Rockefeller Center Monday                      135.0
                   Tuesday                     237.0
```

*Note you may need to make a few modifications so that it works with your actual data since you don't actually specify if all the locations are stored in one dataframe, etc.*

Comment: Accepted. Looks like converting date to date-time in Pandas upfront seems to make life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, you can convert it directly by:

```
s.dt.strftime('%A')
```